# Do online webhosting accounts allow the customers to install and run webservers like node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, web-hosting

I have designed a website that uses node.js and socket.io for the onsite instant messaging system. However, for running node.js, we need to run the node.js server module on the webserver as we all know that node.js is server side javascript. So, for this, I would need to install node.js and socket.io in the webserver and then run node.js server. Do the online webhosting accounts like those of godaddy.com or ipage.com allow the user to install stuff and run a server like node.js? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Three of the most famous webhost providers ( two of them especially popular for node.js )

1. Heroku - [doesn't support Websockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku).
2. Nodejitsu - [support Websockets](http://nodejitsu.com/paas.html)
3. Amazon web services - support Websockets too...

Use them. There are a lot of materials on the Internet on how to run socket.io application using those services. I don't think that even if ipage.com supports websockets they have documented it!

There is a pretty good list with services that provide Websockets in [NodeJS Wiki/Hosting](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting) page!

Comment: Al present I am running my website in my MAMP server. Just trying to find out a good yet cost effective solution to host my website.